# HOw to use bluetooth of the device using worklight

Tags: bluetooth, ibm-mobilefirst

Any help on how to get handle to bluetooth apis in worklight.

Is it possible in worklight?

Answer (score 1):

Worklight does not provide any Bluetooth APIs, so what exactly are you referring to?

There are Cordova plug-ins that provide some sort of interface and there are Bluetooth APIs provided by Apple, Google, etc.

In both cases you can use them [by implementing a Cordova plug-in in Worklight](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_native_to_hybrid).

- Search google for various Cordova plug-ins providing Bluetooth functionality and implement them based on the training module by Worklight
- Or implement a Cordova plug-in that will access [the API Apple provides](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257) (or the same for other vendors)

Comment: I am pretty new to worklight. So if I implement the cordova plugins providing blue tooth functionality will it work for all devices. From your reply it seems we need to implement seperately for apple

Comment: Each vendor is likely to implement their own API of the Bluetooth standard, so you'll likely need a plug-in per environment. Cordova will allow you to access that API from your Worklight application.

Comment: @user3736741, if this answer helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.